# Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, permission-denied

With the below code I receive `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`, and I know this is due to the output directory being a sub-folder of the input directory:

```
import datetime
import os

inputdir = "C:\\temp2\\CSV\\"
outputdir = "C:\\temp2\\CSV\\output\\"
keyword = "KEYWORD"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(inputdir)):
    for f in os.listdir(inputdir):
        file_path = os.path.join(inputdir, f)
        out_file = os.path.join(outputdir, f)
        with open(file_path, "r") as fh, open(out_file, "w") as fo:
            for line in fh:
                if keyword not in line:
                    fo.write(line)
```

However, when I change the output folder to: `outputdir = "C:\\temp2\\output\\"` the code runs successfully. I want to be able to write the modified files to a sub-folder of the input directory. How would I do this without getting the 'Permission denied' error? Would the `tempfile` module be useful in this scenario?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write there? I would use `tempfile`, personally, as it's cleaner.

Comment: could you make fh as writable as well?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you use raw strings then the double-backslashes won't be necessary. Example: `r"C:\Temp1\CSV\Output\"` vs. `"C:\\Temp1\CSV\\Output\\"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Li-aung. =)

Comment: First you should understand how `walk` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` will return directory as well as file names.  `output` is within `inputdir` so the `with` is trying to open a directory for reading/writing.

What exactly are you trying to do?  `path, dirs, files` aren't even being used in the recursive `os.walk`.

**Edit:** I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import os

INPUTDIR= "c:\\temp2\\CSV"
OUTPUTDIR = "c:\\temp2\\CSV\\output"
keyword = "KEYWORD"

def make_path(p):
    '''Makes sure directory components of p exist.'''
    try:
        os.makedirs(p)
    except OSError:
        pass

def dest_path(p):
    '''Determines relative path of p to INPUTDIR,
       and generates a matching path on OUTPUTDIR.
    '''
    path = os.path.relpath(p,INPUTDIR)
    return os.path.join(OUTPUTDIR,path)

make_path(OUTPUTDIR)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(INPUTDIR):
    for d in dirs:
        dir_path = os.path.join(path,d)
        # Handle case of OUTPUTDIR inside INPUTDIR
        if dir_path == OUTPUTDIR:
            dirs.remove(d)
            continue
        make_path(dest_path(dir_path))    
    for f in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(path, f)
        out_path = dest_path(file_path)
        with open(file_path, "r") as fh, open(out_path, "w") as fo:
            for line in fh:
                if keyword not in line:
                    fo.write(line)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still fairly new to Python. Currently I just have a flat directory of CSV files that I want to process -- delete lines and save the modified CSV files to an output folder within the input folder. However, there might be a time where I have folders/sub-folders of CSV files that I want to process, so I want to be sure I can handle that scenario too.

Comment: It complicates matters to recurse over a directory while modifying it at the same time.  It can be done by modifying `dirs` and removing output directory when it is seen, but simpler to keep the output directory outside the input directory.

You don't actually need `os.listdir`.  `for f in files` along with `file_path = os.path.join(path,f)` will give you the full path of every file, recursively, under the input dir.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Mark. I will look into your suggestions. I agree that it's simpler to keep the output dir outside the input dir, however, other people on my team who will be using this tool that I'm creating would prefer to have the output dir within the input dir. I've already accomplished this using PowerShell (which doesn't seem to have these complications), but I want to take advantage of Python's text processing power. In some cases I will have millions of lines in CSV files to process and want a more powerful tool to handle the job.

Comment: I updated my answer with something that would work the way you want.  Re: PowerShell, did that version recurse?  Comment out the `# Handle case...` portion above and you'll see how it complicates things.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tested your above code and it works great! Thank you. And RE: PowerShell - yes, it does recurse. =)

Comment: BTW, in case you're interested, here is the code to do the same thing above in PowerShell: `Get-ChildItem $FilePath $Ext -recurse |
 % {
  $content = ($_ | Get-Content)
  $content | ? {$_ -notmatch $Keyword} | Set-Content $FilePath\output\$_
 }`  Less lines of code, but much slower than Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you are successful in writing to a output directory outside of the input traversing directory, then write it there first using the same code as above and then move it to a sub-directory within the input directory. You could use `os.move` for that.

Comment: Hi Senthil, I actually thought about using `os.move` but wasn't sure if that approach would be less efficient. I could give it a try...

Comment: Hi Keith, that's not less efficiently, it's a good approach. In fact, writing to a location outside of the your reading location would be better. And then you could atomically move to the final destination.